# Can't remove a board in Quiver

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have been working in Quiver and I was writing a sequence of transformations. I wanted to delete a chart in Quiver, however, I wasn't able to. What Quiver says is that *Card is used by other cards*, see screenshot below.

[image]

The chart is the last chart in the transformation sequence. I checked every possible connections to different cards, however I didn't find any.

Do you know if there are some "hidden" connections in Quiver between cards to check that would allow me to delete the chart?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like it might be a bug or at least related to your specific Quiver workbook - I'd recommend getting in touch with the Foundry Support team through the Help Center and they can lend a hand.